# How to switch tty with a script / cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, tty

Is it possible to switch the current tty/vt with the help of a bash script or a cronjob? I only know the physical keyboard input "Ctrl-Alt-Fx".
I would like to show two virtual desktops at different daytimes (controlled by cron).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You're looking for the [chvt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chvt) command.